# Can we have a proper review queue for proposed changes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-queues

I've been going through proposed changes to Documentation, and I'm already missing some of the features that we get in a review queue.

- Streamlined workflow is about my biggest issue: instead of reviewing one proposal and then being presented with the next, I have to click back to a previous page, refresh to find something that hasn't been reviewed, and then enter individual review for that item.
- Options other than Approve and Reject are missing. We could *really* do with Approve and Edit and perhaps Reject and Edit.
- Much as they are hated, review audits might (eventually) turn out to be necessary... I have noticed cases of people spam-approving everything, where a considered rejection might have worked better.

In short, can we have a proper review queue for these instead of an inelegant workflow? It doesn't have to be in /review, but a Docs-specific review section would be welcome.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers We should tag the duplicate target with status-planned as well.

Comment: @dorukayhan good call, doing it now.